# Why are the results of a chkdsk scan on drive C: not showing in the event viewer, but chkdsk results for N: are?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, eventviewer, chkdsk

On a Server 2008 R2 member server I schedule chkdsk to check drives `C:` and `N:`.  Only the results for the `N:` drive are seen in event viewer. In previous Windows Servers, chkdsk results for drive `C:` appeared in event viewer. Is that still the case or is there another reason why I'm not seeing chkdsk's results in event viewer? There is no boot log to be seen either.

Comment: The following link had some good discussion, but i tried everything in it, nothing.  No boot log i suppose that might be turned on with msconfig.exe, but i would rather not.  There are no WinInit entries in my event log.  WinLogon does not have the results either.   http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2010/11/where-to-find-chkdsk-results/